# 50% noise on USB Microphone

Tags: usb, kubuntu, pulseaudio, audio-recording

I've got an wireless mircophone with USB Interface (namely Rode Wireless GO II, recognized as a digital IEC958 Input). When connecting to my kubuntu 22.04 notebook the input stream over the USB connection always produces a white noise. You can also hear the microphone input if I am screaming, but the noise is much louder. The noise seem to have 50% level. Every application that I've tested so far has this noise which makes the microphone unusable **except audacity**. When recording from the digital USB Interface from that input in audacity using ALSA, the input is perfectly silent and the microphone works as expected (input level a bit low but there is no noise visible at all). When using the same configuration (ALSA and the digital input 2,0) i.E. in Teamspeak 3, the heavy noise is present.

How can I reconfigure the audio stack that this noise is not there system-wide? Audacity seems to handle the incoming data in a different way (a way the data is meant to be by the microphone hardware). When using the digital input on windows, everything works fine system-wide.

Some Information about the system:

Devices:

```
arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX20753/4 Analog [CX20753/4 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Audi [ThinkPad OneLink Plus Dock Audi], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: RX [Wireless GO II RX], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

stream info:

```
cat /proc/asound/card2/stream0 
RØDE Wireless GO II RX at usb-0000:00:14.0-3, full speed : USB Audio

Capture:
  Status: Stop
  Interface 2
    Altset 1
    Format: S24_3LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 0x83 (3 IN) (ASYNC)
    Rates: 48000
    Bits: 24
    Channel map: FL FR
  Interface 2
    Altset 2
    Format: S16_LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 0x83 (3 IN) (ASYNC)
    Rates: 48000
    Bits: 16
    Channel map: FL FR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but the update to Kubuntu 22.10 removed this kind of behaviour. I am not even able to select pulseaudio as an option in more applications next to ALSA